# c++ pass 2D array as argument to function?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm making a tic tac toe game.  I'm trying to pass a multi dimensional array into a function.

This is my code:

```
void printBoard(int board[3][3]) {

    for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            if (board[j - 1][i - 1] == 0)
                cout << "_  ";
            if (board[j - 1][i - 1] == 1)
                cout << "O ";
            if (board[j - 1][i - 1] == 2)
                cout << "X ";
            if ((i % 3 == 0))
                cout << "\n";
        }
    }//end 1st for
}//end function
```

I keep getting errors.  I have done research and I have successfully passed a 1D array as an argument using pointers.

Here is that code:

```
void display(int *p, int len){

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i ++){
        std::cout << "\n" << *(p + i);
    }//end for
}//end function
```

How can I do this with a multi array?

Comment: nothing is wrong with your code at all. Could you specify the errors

Comment: also, could you show us how you are calling the function

Comment: There's about a million duplicates to be found here, I don't see how this one adds any value for future research.

Comment: You may get rid of `-1` with loop from 0 to 3 instead of 1 to 4.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
int board[3][3];
//..
printBoard(board);
```

Following (and your method) is correct:

```
void printBoard(const int (&board)[3][3]) {
    for (const auto& a : board) {
        for (int e : a) {
            switch (e) {
                case 0: std::cout << "_  "; break;
                case 1: std::cout << "O  "; break;
                case 2: std::cout << "X  "; break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for passing a multi array to argument.

First, when creating your function, leave out the first number in the bracket. Ie

```
void printBoard(int board[][3]){}
```

And when calling your function do this.

```
printBoard(board);
```

Sorry if it's weird to answer your own question but it helped me a lot. 
Courtesy to http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-2d-array-parameter-c/

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using pointer style passing. For a 2D array it would look like:

```
void display(int **board, int width, int height) {
  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
       if (board[i][j] == ...
```

Comment: Caveat: `int board[3][3]` does not decay into `int **`